# Why are Emacs Eshell and macOS default terminal showing different results for the same query on a program (SDKMAN) version?

Tags: osx, terminal-emacs, eshell, bash

I am using Emacs ([config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el)) on macOS Monterey (12.5).

There is something that I do not understand. After being queried on a specific version of the program called [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) `sdk`, eshell and macOS default terminal present different outputs!!

On MacOS default terminal:

```bash
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air learn-cljs % sdk v

SDKMAN 5.15.0
```

Now, eshell returns a different output:

```bash
Welcome to the Emacs shell

 ~ $ cd projects/
 ~/projects $ cd learn-cljs/
 ~/projects/learn-cljs $ sdk -v
sdk: command not found
```

I am new to macOS but I have been using Emacs for a while on Linux machines. I was shocked by this behavior. I have never seen such asymmetry.

I know eshell has limited behavior compared to the default terminal even in Linux (for instance, htop does not work - by design). But this was a big surprise.

I have tried following @[db48x](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9982/db48x)'s kind advice described below, but I can't make it work.

After using `set-variable` to tweak the value of `exec-path`, doing `describe-variable` on `exec-path` indicates:

```lisp
("/opt/homebrew/bin" "/opt/homebrew/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/Users/pedro/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin" "/Users/pedro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/opt/X11/bin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec")
```

As you see, SDKman is the fourth element on `exec-path` variable. However, `eshell` still indicates: `sdk: command not found`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eshell is a shell. It is true that programs that need a terminal, such as htop, won’t work in Eshell. However, that is a separate issue.

When you run a command in a shell, it is customary for the shell to first match the command name against its list of built–in commands, and then to search for executable programs in a configured set of directories. By convention, the list of directories to search is stored in an environment variable called `PATH`. Most users will set this variable by editing a shell startup file, and most operating systems provide some kind of default value that will be used when the user hasn’t done this yet.

But different shells have different startup files. Anytime you try out a new shell, you will find that your customizations from your old shell aren’t there, because they live in a startup file that your new shell doesn’t know about. This is a good thing, because the command syntax and available customizations might differ greatly between shells.

The default shell on OSX is either bash or zsh (I don’t use OSX so I don’t know for sure which.) Bash looks for `~/.bashrc` as a startup file, and zsh looks for `~/.zshrc`.¹

Eshell doesn’t have a separate startup file; it just uses variables which can be set or configured as part of your Emacs environment. The values of those variables come from your Emacs init file, which is usually `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.²

To control the PATH in Eshell, customize the `exec-path` variable. You can do this by tying `M-x customize-variable` and then entering `exec-path` when prompted.

Edit: if [this is the sdkman you are asking about](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli), then **there is simply no way to run it in eshell**. It was written entirely in Bash scripts, so it’s not compatible with other shells.

¹: Naturally this is greatly simplified; they both look for multiple files. Check their manpages for the details.

²: Also simplified; see the Emacs manual for details.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the default of macOS (previously called OSX) is `zsh` but `bash`is also available. Also, the program looks for the `.bash_profile` file not `.bashrc`.

Comment: After doing a `describe-variable`on `exec-path`, this is what I get: `exec-path is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

Its value is
("/Users/pedro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin" "/Users/pedro/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec")`

Comment: thanks for the help. After executing customize-variable and choosing exec-path, what should I choose?

Comment: You’re trying to let it find the `sdk` program, so you need to add whatever directory that program lives in to the list.

Comment: Also, in re the difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`: I said that I was simplifying things :)

Comment: Oh, and if you don’t know what directory `sdk` is in, go to the shell where it works and run `type sdk`. It will tell you that `sdk is hashed (/some/path/to/sdk)`. That’s the directory you want to use.

Comment: thanks, @db48x. I am still trying to fix this. Unfortunately, `type SDK` does *not* return the path to SDK. It returns `~ pedro$ type sdk
sdk is a function
sdk () 
{  ... a lot of content... `

Comment: I believe I found it: `/Users/pedro/.sdkman/bin`

Comment: Fascinating. It is quite rare for software to install a shell function like that. For one thing, there are many shells out there and you cannot count on you users to always use the ones you already support.

Comment: My previous `exec-path` variable value: `("/opt/homebrew/bin" "/opt/homebrew/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/Users/pedro/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin" "/Users/pedro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/opt/X11/bin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec")`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it still does not work @db48x. I will update my question with the new information I have after following your advice.

Comment: Is there an executable file called `sdk` in the directory that you added to `exec-path`? If not, then typing `sdk` won’t do anything.

Comment: The only file on `~/.sdkman/bin` is `sdkman-init.sh`.... Not sure how to proceed. What do you suggest?

Comment: Wait, is it this file? https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/blob/master/src/main/bash/sdkman-init.sh

Comment: After `type sdk` on my terminal shell, this is what I get: https://github.com/pdelfino/deprecated-my-emacs-config/blob/main/help-from-stack-overflow.md

Comment: Wait. You want the `sdkman-init.sh`. I will post it too: https://github.com/pdelfino/deprecated-my-emacs-config/blob/main/sdkman-init.sh

Comment: It is the same file, with concrete values instead of abstracted values in some parts.

Comment: Not sure if the problem below is related, but another question emerged as I was trying to fix this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73241/how-to-make-changes-on-variables-values-be-persistent-over-sessions

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. How do I know if this is the SDKman I have?

Comment: You already confirmed it.

Comment: Thank you. I never thought this could be a problem... I thought shells had some kind of inter-operability considering how stable and uniform they seem...