# How to make changes on variables' values be persistent over sessions?

Tags: eshell, variables, session, persistence

The current question is related to a [previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72890/why-emacs-eshell-and-macos-default-terminal-are-showing-different-results-for-th) which is still not fully solved.

I have been doing the following:

1 - After executing `describe-variable` over `exec-path`, I get:

```lisp
("/opt/homebrew/bin" "/opt/homebrew/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/Users/pedro/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin" "/Users/pedro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/opt/X11/bin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec")
```

2 -  Due to the previous discussion above mentioned, I want `sdkman` to work on `eshell`! Thus, I am changing the path to point to the binary folder with shell file.
Which is means tweaking from `"/Users/pedro/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin"` to `"/Users/pedro/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`.

```lisp
("/opt/homebrew/bin" "/opt/homebrew/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/Users/pedro/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" "/Users/pedro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/opt/X11/bin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-arm64-11" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec")
```

3 - Ok, if I execute again the `describe-variable` command over `exec-path` things work out well! I have the **new** value.

The problem is when I **re-start** Emacs, the value is back to the original one!

Thus, I would like to ask: How to make this change persistent over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides `desktop.el`, which is likely overkill for just persisting some variable values. Here are two other approaches.

1. You can use library `savehist.el` (part of vanilla Emacs) to persist any variable values. Just customize option `savehist-additional-variables`.
2. With [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) you can create bookmarks that restore sets of [variable values](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#FunctionSequenceVarlistBookmarks). Just jump to a bookmark to set a bunch of variables in a particular way.

You may not want to use #2 if all you want to do is persist a few variables. But if you use Bookmark+ for other reasons then you already have this possibility. And if you want to be able to restore different sets of variable values on demand, then this can be useful.

Comment: Great! I like the `savehist.el`.  (It saves things in the file `savehist-file`.)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is edit your init file to include a call to `add-to-list`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Users/pedro/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin")
```

But note that this won’t magically make the `sdkman` software compatible with Eshell; that would involve rewriting `sdkman`. Also, `exec-path` is a list of directories, adding shell scripts to it won’t do anything useful.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this approach with a difference variable here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73331/why-changing-the-value-of-this-variable-via-add-to-list-is-not-working. But, it did not work. Not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

If you use `desktop.el`, you can add `exec-path` to the customization option `desktop-globals-to-save`. This is a list of variables that `desktop-mode` will save and restore across sessions.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I am surprise there is a need for a package to change this...

Comment: If my understanding is correct, this is an old package, right? Is it possible to install it with `use-package`?   https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/desktop.el. I tried it here and it seems to work...

Comment: I am searching for `desktop-globals-to-save` as a command. But, I can't find it. Is it a command?

Comment: No, a user option (a variable you can customize).

Comment: `desktop.el` is built in.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the GNU elpa package [persist.el](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/persist.html), which is made for persisting variables specifically. The two relevant functions are `persist-defvar` and `persist--save-all` (which the package does call on the emacs quit hook, but in case of crashing, you might like to put it on a timer)