# Why changing the value of this variable via add-to-list is not working?

Tags: variables, list

Usually, I do the following to change a variable's value:

1 - I execute the command `set-variable`

2 - I pick `cider-shadow-cljs-command`

3 - I tweak the value changing it to be `"shadow-cljs"`

It works. However, it is painful to do this every time. Thus, I would
like to make the changes persist over time.

Hence, I edited my `init.el` file to have the following snippet:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'cider-shadow-cljs-command "shadow-cljs")
```

Unfortunately, if I restart Emacs, an error is retrieved:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/pedro/.emacs.d/init.el`:
> Wrong type argument: listp, npx shadow-cljs

This is the original value:

```lisp
(defcustom cider-shadow-cljs-command
  "npx shadow-cljs"
  "The command used to execute shadow-cljs.

By default we favor the project-specific shadow-cljs over the system-wide."
  :type 'string
  :safe #'stringp
  :package-version '(cider . "0.17.0"))
```

How can I fix this? Should I use a different command than `add-to-list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `set-variable` interactively, not `add-to-list`, so I think the corresponding elisp code would be either:

```
(setq cider-shadow-cljs-command "shadow-cljs")
```

or

```
(customize-set-variable 'cider-shadow-cljs-command "shadow-cljs")
```

The setq only works if you run that *after* cider is loaded, and the customize-set-variable will work even if you run it before cider is loaded (it is meant for defcustom variables), so I would recommend customize-set-variable in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Is `setq` permanent across different sessions of Emacs? After I quit and re-start is it still going to hold the value?

Comment: You put these forms in your init.el and then they will persist!

Answer (score 2):

`add-to-list` expects the value of its first argument to be a list. You're passing it symbol `cider-shadow-cljs-command` as first arg, and the value of that variable is a string, not a list.