# Is it possible to save register values and restore them in another session?

Tags: variables, registers, persistence

I use registers (such as `C-x r s 0`) as a multi-valued clipboard that can save different contents (`copy-to-register`). Then I can "paste" the value using `C-x r i 0`. This is really convenient, but all the register values are lost if I close Emacs.

*Is it possible to save these register values into a file somewhere and restore them when I open a new Emacs session?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make changes on variables' values be persistent over sessions?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73241/how-to-make-changes-on-variables-values-be-persistent-over-sessions)

Answer (score 2):

`register-alist`:

> *Alist* of elements `(NAME . CONTENTS)`, one for each Emacs register.

Here is an example:

```lisp
;; ~/.emacs.d/init.el  -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(require 'register)

(let ((my/registers-file "~/.emacs.d/my-registers.el"))
  (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
            (lambda ()
              (with-temp-file my/registers-file
                (insert (prin1-to-string register-alist)))))
  (when (file-exists-p my/registers-file)
    (setq register-alist (with-temp-buffer
                           (insert-file my/registers-file)
                           (read (current-buffer))))))
```

Comment: That's probably going to work for strings, numbers and rectangles but it is unlikely to work for window/frame configurations, buffer positions and other such things that are not necessarily preserved across sessions (although `desktop-mode` might help with some of these too).

Comment: @NickD: Thank you for the additional information, I forgot to remind OP about these precautions. Actually, I believe the ultimate solution to all these problems is to use an Emacs server; I recommend that OP learn about it.

Comment: Or just add `register-alist` to `savehist-additional-variables` (and use `savehist.el`). Also: search for tags `[persistence]` and `[variables]` here.